# Convergence of the sequence $0.1, 0.1001, 0.100100001....$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

consider the sequence of rational numbers $\{q_k\}_{k\geq1}$ where $q_k=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{10^{n^2}}$ i.e $q_1=0.1$, $q_2=0.1001$, $q_3=0.100100001$ etc. Is it bounded? Is it Cauchy? Does it convergent in Q?

So I proved that the sequence is bounded and Cauchy but couldn't able to show whether it is convergent in Q or not. We know that every Cauchy sequence is convergent in R but how to conclude in this case? Help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This series fails to converge in $\mathbb{Q}$, since its decimal expansion is non-terminating and non-periodic. To check the second point, it suffices to note that the decimal expansion of the sum will be exactly

$$0.1001000010000001000...$$
contains a non-zero entry at position $i$ if and only if $i$ is a perfect square.

Comment: So any non-terminating sequence in Q is not convergent in Q right?

Comment: @user290591 Having a non-terminating decimal expansion is just fine - take, for example, $1/3 = 0.333...$. The problem is that *both* non-terminating and non-periodic are a problem.

Comment: Oh. So this sequence is convergent to  a irrational number .

Comment: @user290591 Yes, exactly.

Comment: Ok thanks, very helpful.

Comment: How did you prove that this sequence is Cauchy? Can you please explain the solution to this question?